# How to regex an email address within a line of text, naviely?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a line of text (string) which contain some email addresses. I know there are like a million posts on email regex, but in this question my definition of email address is just a string of characters with no space in between and contains exactly one '@' symbol.

> e.g. Lazy dog jump over the fence@quick brown fox's house. And when I
>   need a sample text_I/just@randomly.think of words to type.

This will give me `fence@quick` and `text_I/just@randomly.think` as a valid match.

I tried `new Regex(@"\b.*@.*\b")` but it matches the entire line of text, although that claims to be the word boundary meta character?

I actually got it to work with `new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*")` but is there a simpler way? EDIT: This still misses some invalid email address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: @PLB, please read the question again. I want a naive match, not something that follows the standard. Thanks.

Comment: you have space in email address?

Comment: @VigneshVino no space. just .*@.* in a word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this regex

```
\S+@\S+
```

`\S` would match any character that is not space

But even space is a valid character in email.so use it cautiously..

---

Have a look at these articles

- [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Complicated Regular Expressions](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)
- [Simple Explanation of E-mail address format (RFC 822)](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/822addr.html)
- [Email Address format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)
- [RFC 822 Standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt)

Bottom line is these standards have never been followed so its better to stick with
`^[^@]+@[^@]+$`

Comment: I know this said "naively", but just out of curiosity, can you have an email without a dot after the `@`?

Comment: @Alxandr as specified in the docs:  the domain must match the requirements for a hostname, consisting of letters, digits, hyphens and **dots**

Comment: @Alxandr see it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Domain_part) also refer to above links

Comment: @Alxandr well it seems to be optional cause `admin@mailserver1` is valid emailid

Comment: `postbox@com (top-level domains are valid hostnames)`... WOW o.O